# Can I arrange all my apps on Heroku to run on the same LAN?

Tags: networking, heroku, client-server, zeromq

I'm looking to host a Python webapp on Heroku. The backend is written in different Java programs (the servers) and ZeroMQ is used for communication. If I deploy everything on Heroku (the servers just need to be running listening to requests), would they all run on the same LAN?

I'm asking because I don't want to run ZeroMQ over the internet, cause then I'll need something like SSH tunneling which I want to avoid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynos do not share the same network. [See this article on Heroku's website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#network-interfaces). This is by design for resiliance but you can choose the (Amazon) region that they all reside in.